# In micosost excel how do i copy data from multiple columns in a row to one column in same row

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[please click here >> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6ow2.png)]

i have the following table with multiple hosts port numbers uri as shown above, if i want to make the usable uri by getting the values these  multiple rows into a column of same row, is there any formula which i can use once and make the uri for all the hosts in different rows ?

i have tried the following but it has to done each and every time for column 
=C2&"://"&A2&":"&"/"&D2

Is there any ay the above formula is written only once and i can use for other rows to build the url

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just drag the formula down, and the cell references should auto-adjust

Comment: If the Rows are identical you can drag it down it will work

Comment: Thank you Ron and yass. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the formula that you have already in one cell, and drag the fill handle to the full range. If there are 1000s of rows, then just double click the fill handle. This will assign formulas to all rows accordingly

Comment: @vineelbharath Thanks!! Kindly upvote my answer if you found this is useful.